# Power BI: Subtract current row from previous row

Tags: powerbi, dax, m

Hi I have a below requirement.
I have a table named forcast table with forecast version and values.
I need to initially calculate the sum of values for each forecast. and subtract the forecast from the previous row(for 2022.7: I need to take 2022.8 and subtract 2022.7, for 2022.8: I need to take 2022.9 and subtract 2022.8 and so on)
Atlast, I have to build a graph with the differences.
Please find the clear requirement in below link.
https://github.com/samantha280/powerbi/blob/main/Book2.xlsx

Comment: Could you show what you've tried?  Consider using `LAG()`

Answer (score 0):

powerquery / M on your forecast table

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Forecast", type number}, {"Vals", Int64.Type}}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Forecast"}, {{"Vals", each List.Sum([Vals]), type nullable number}}),
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Custom", each try [Vals]-#"Added Index"{[Index]-1}[Vals] otherwise null),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom", each ([Custom] <> null)),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Vals", "Index"})
in  #"Removed Columns"
```